# Elementarity of mappings

Tags: set-theory

I have a short question regarding elementarity of mappings,

i.e. I am doing some models of set theory and very often one says that a certain mapping is elementary.

I wonder what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal L$ be a (first order) language and let $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ be $\mathcal{L}$-structures. A map
$$
\pi \colon \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}
$$
is *elementary* iff for every $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi$ and all $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathcal{M}$
$$
\mathcal{M} \models \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \iff \mathcal{N} \models \phi(\pi(x_1), \ldots, \pi(x_n)).
$$

We also say that $\pi$ is an elementary embedding.

[Note that $\pi$ is always injective, since for $x,y \in \mathcal{M}$
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi(x) = \pi(y) & \iff \mathcal N \models \pi(x) = \pi(y) \\
& \iff \mathcal M \models x = y  \\ 
& \iff x = y,
\end{align*}
$$
which justifies the use of the term *embedding* in this context.]